# TweepError: Failed to send request: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Setup OSX 10.7.4, Eclipse, Pydev, Python 2.7, Tweepy-1.9

Hey, I was originally trying to grab tweets from the twitter API but kept getting the same error as below. This program is designed to print the twitter API rate limit to make sure I am not gone over.

I keep getting this error but there is very little info online about it.

Any help is appreciated.

The Code

```
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(Consumer Key, Consumer Secret)
auth.set_access_token(Access token,Access token secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

print api.rate_limit_status()
#print tweepy.api.rate_limit_status()
```

The Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brendan/Documents/workspace/Euro2012/src/rate_limit.py", line 7, in <module>
    print api.rate_limit_status()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 185, in _call
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 149, in execute
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

EDIT: I have no confirmation on this as yet but I suspect the problem is with proxy settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, tweepy uses the low-level [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) instead of the high-level [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html). httplib does not use HTTP proxies; it is used by other modules to *implement* HTTP proxy support.

Either get an internet connection that allows direct connections without proxy configuration, or modify tweepy to use urllib2, or use another library.

Answer (score 1):

phihag above was correct. The standard versions of Tweepy do not have HTTP support. However there is a version (1.7.3) created by DUCU which can be downloaded here at [GitHub](https://github.com/ducu/tweepy) that apparently does have HTTP support with some modification. I had to use the latest version (1.9) as I had an issue with outdated libraries.

My solution, as suggested by phihag, was to use an alternative internet connection.

It would be interesting to see if future versions of Tweepy will have HTTP support.

Keywords (for other searchers) Tweepy API http proxy support.